# How would I move a file created into the directory I have just made?

Tags: python

I am making a calendar system in python that creates a file with a description as its contents. That file will be placed into a directory with files with the same date to allow for detection of overlapping events.

I have attempted to use shutil to move the file in once created but I am having no luck as well as setting the directory to the new folder. (Apologies for the poor coding, I am new to python and haven't quite got to grips with formatting and the best way to solve these logical problems).

```
def newEvent():  # Creates new event
    directory = input("Input the calender directory. This can be changed in the settings: ")
    pattern = "^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]).(1[0-2]|0[1-9]).[0-9]{4}$"  # DD.MM.YYY Pattern
    eventName = input("Please enter the name of the event: ")
    print("'" + eventName + "'" + " successfully Registered.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    eventDate = input("Please enter the date of the event in the 'DD.MM.YYYY' format: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if re.match(pattern, eventDate):  # Matches pattern with eventDate
        print(eventName + " successfully Registered on the " + eventDate)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        description = input("Please input a description for the event: ")
        time.sleep(0.5)


        if os.path.exists(re.sub('\.', '', eventDate)):
            fileName = str(re.sub('\.', '', eventDate)) + "/" + eventDate + " - " + eventName + ".txt"  # Creates the file name

            newFile = open(str(fileName), "w+")  # Creates the file
            newFile.write(description)  # Adds description
            newFile.close()
        else:
            newDir = os.mkdir((re.sub('\.', '', eventDate)))  # Creates new directory named the event date minus the "."
            fileName = "/" + eventDate + " - " + eventName + ".txt"

            newFile = open(str(directory) + (fileName), "w+")
            newFile.write(description)
            newFile.close()
            shutil.move(str(newFile), str(newDir))
        print("Your event: " + str(eventName) + " taking place on the " + eventDate + " has been registered. Returning to menu.")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        menu()
    else:
        print("Date not valid, returning to 'New Event'.")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        newEvent()
```

I would like the code to move the newFile into the created directory but it creates the file in the directory of the .py file.

Comment: maybe os.path.join()

Comment: Change fileName = “/” ... to ”.\“

Comment: Regular expression patterns should use have an `r` prefix on them so backslash character aren't interpreted as escape characters. i.e.: `r'\.'` You can use `shutil.move()` to move files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the definition of the paths. 
Also you're trying to move newFile which is a TextWrapper instance and not a path string or path-like object (but you convert it to string so the terminal doesn't give you the right error message)

I suggest you to use os.path.join to create the paths: it's more clean, less error prone, and multi-platform so that you don't have to worry between windows and linux path separator (\ or /)

Moreover, you can directly define your filename with the correct absolute path, so that you don't have to move anything

```
def newEvent():  # Creates new event
    directory = input("Input the calender directory. This can be changed in the settings: ")
    pattern = "^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]).(1[0-2]|0[1-9]).[0-9]{4}$"  # DD.MM.YYY Pattern
    eventName = input("Please enter the name of the event: ")
    print("'" + eventName + "'" + " successfully Registered.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    eventDate = input("Please enter the date of the event in the 'DD.MM.YYYY' format: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if re.match(pattern, eventDate):  # Matches pattern with eventDate
        print(eventName + " successfully Registered on the " + eventDate)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        description = input("Please input a description for the event: ")
        time.sleep(0.5)

        event_dir = os.path.join(directory, re.sub('\.', '', eventDate))
        fileName = os.path.join(directory, event_dir, eventDate + " - " + eventName + ".txt")  # Creates the file name
        if os.path.exists(event_dir):
            newFile = open(str(fileName), "w+")  # Creates the file
            newFile.write(description)  # Adds description
            newFile.close()
        else:
            newDir = os.mkdir(event_dir)  # Creates new directory named the event date minus the "."
            newFile = open(fileName, "w+")
            newFile.write(description)
            newFile.close()
            # shutil.move(str(fileName), str(newDir))
        print("Your event: " + str(eventName) + " taking place on the " + eventDate + " has been registered. Returning to menu.")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        menu()
    else:
        print("Date not valid, returning to 'New Event'.")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        newEvent()
```